# I am trying to set up a data sharing, how do I automate when the data access expire?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to set up a Data Share with an expiration date, I am not sure how to do that. So far here is how I set it up:

```
//create resource monitor

CREATE RESOURCE MONITOR GPDATA WITH CREDIT_QUOTA = 100
triggers on 75 percent do notify
             on 100 percent do suspend
             on 110 percent do suspend_immediate;

//Create Warehouse
create warehouse "MarketshareWH"
  AUTO_SUSPEND = TRUE
  RESOURCE_MONITOR = GPDATA
  COMMENT = 'Shared market data lies here';

create database market_shared_db from share bd56789.share;
```

The Warehouse auto-suspends and has a resource monitor, can I set an expiration on the share or should I create a task to remove grants on a share?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not expert here, but as I understand it a `share` is shared between accounts (not warehouses which is a separate compute context) and not users (which belong to an account). Are you sharing this `bd56789.share` to another account? Furthermore I don't think you can limit how much a share is used by the consumer account of the share nor would it be necessary since it's their account that would be paying Snowflake to query your share. You can revoke access though.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, but the closest thing you can do to expiring a data share is dropping it. You can set up a task for when it's supposed to expire and just

```
DROP SHARE <name>
```

The Resource Monitor does not have an option to expire; however, even if it did that's not where you'd want to set an expiration. The reason is the users would still have access to the shared account, even though they couldn't run anything requiring a running warehouse.

If you do drop the share, you'll lose any user logins set up there. If you'd rather keep that for potential future use, your best option is to revoke the grants.